# simple login test scenarios

Tags: test-management, testcase

Course Name: Software Quality Assurance

I need 25 test scenarios to verify user login that contains just two fields

1. User Name
2. Password

It may be Positive scenario or negative scenario.

Comment: And how many do you already have? and can you post them. We are not here to do your homework. Maybe we can help you find the missing few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very unusual to write test scenarios with such limited information. I only write simplified tests as it can be developed into scenarios easily.

Assume pressing enter in password field would initial login, and below logins are valid,

- username: correct, password: correct
- username: correct1, password: correct1
- username: speical1, password: #$%^&*()!
- username: longpass, password: 123456789012345678901234567890

[blank] means no character is input

1. positive. username: correct, press ENTER, password: correct. Show welcome page.
2. positive. username: correct, press TAB, password: correct
3. positive. username: correct , password: correct. Assume space at the end will be trimmed
4. positive. username: correct1, password: correct1
5. positive. username: speical1, password: #$%^&*()!. Test special characters in password.
6. positive. username: longpass, password: 123456789012345678901234567890
7. positive/negative. username: longpass, password: 12345678901234567890. Some system trims long password while some doesn't
8. negative. username: correct1, password: correct. Show login error.
9. negative. username: correct, password: correct1
10. negative. username: [blank], password: [blank]. Show username required.
11. negative. username: correct, password: [blank]. Show password required.
12. negative. username: [blank], password: correct. Show username required.
13. negative. username: correct, password: wrong. Show login error.
14. negative. username: wrong, password: correct

Case sensitiveness. It depends on whether the login/password is case sensitive/insensitive.

15. positive/negative. username: CORRECT, password: correct.
16. positive/negative. username: correct, password: CORRECT.

SQL Injection

17. negative. username: ' OR '1'='1, password: correct
18. negative. username: correct, password: ' OR '1'='1
19. negative. username: " OR "1"="1, password: correct
20. negative. username: correct, password: " OR "1"="1

SQL Injection. Assume the develop check for space but the SQL database allows no space between operator and string

21. negative. username: ' OR '1'='1, password: correct
22. negative. username: correct, password: ' OR '1'='1
23. negative. username: " OR "1"="1, password: correct
24. negative. username: correct, password: " OR "1"="1

Others

25. negative. username: correct, password: correct. should land on the welcome page. Copy URL of the welcome page and then logout. Paste the URL on the browser and press ENTER. The welcome page must not display. It must redirect to login page.

And many more depends on the database you use and your creativity. You need to write another 25 as your tutor is monitoring this question.